# Sql query builder c# for windows mobile

Tags: c#, .net, sql, compact-framework

I'm building a windows mobile app. And using SqlCe.

I'm looking for a good sql query builder. So instead of writing "SELECT COLUMNS FROM TABLE WHERE etc...

Is there a good free library that can build this sort of query?

EDIT:
You know when you write your code with ADO.net something like this

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(Connection);
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customerId = @customerId";
```

Well i'm looking for some library that could build that SELECT statement using classes instead of writing it through string. So something like:

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(Connection);
SqlQueryBuilder query = new SqlQueryBuilder();
query.Table = "Orders";
query.AddWhere("customerId", myValue)
command.CommandText = query.toString();
```

Something like that .... so a class that will build the query..

Comment: Are you saying you want the user of your app to be able to design the query or are you saying you want to be able to design the query?

Comment: @pdiddy, I'll +1 your question if you edit the title of your question but putting "mobile" in there somewhere. This is a good question but it would be better if it was more descriptive of what you are really asking.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, im not looking for a tool for the user. I've edited my question for more descriptive.

Comment: @pdiddy: if you can wait a couple weeks I'm about to release an ORM for the CF with a reference SQL CE implementation that will do all of this for you.

Comment: @ctacke. Cool Is it going to be on codeplex like your IoC?

Comment: yes (it's actually already there, just not yet published while I try to do final tweaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenNETCF.ORM Framework](http://orm.codeplex.com) may do what you want.